# GAS: What is the best alternative do `Brownser.msgBox` in a standalone app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm adapting a spreadsheet app code to an standalone one. But at this line:

```
var addRequest = Browser.msgBox ("Ad more one request text", "Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
```

I'm geting this error (in my language):

```
Can not call Browser.msgBox () from this context; have you tried to use Logger.log ()? (line 450, file "main") [5565/2 of total runtime]
```

So, what is the best alternative do `Brownser.msgBox` in a standalone app?

Comment: Hi, would something like that please you ? https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzLwtgEi9e5WrvDgb_Nz28kjVmcuOcydo2P2MC0NoWRIXXzeXc/exec

Comment: All standalone apps must develop their own interface, and showing an alert in this interface depends a lot on how you implemented it. But the bottom line is, you'll not have any popup that halts your backend execution and returns after it's clicked. You'll have to do that "continuing" yourself.